# A fast way to extract channels data from CVPixelBuffer of ARGB format

Tags: swift, objective-c, image-processing, cvpixelbuffer, accelerate

I have `CVPixelBuffer` that has `kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB` format. I need to extract each channel and store it to separate `CVPixelBuffer`. I imagine the usage of it like this

`let channels: [CVPixelBuffer] = pixBuffer.split()`

So this, for the time being, imaginary function will output 4 CVPixelBuffers of `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8` format.

My question is - is there a fast, convenient and iOS-compliant way to do it? I know how to do it via OpenCV, but my code is in `Swift` and I will need to write complex and not pretty code bouncing `CVPixelBuffer` between `Swift` and `Objective-C`.

I feel that the answer should lie somewhere around `Accelerate` framework. And if I am right, I am pretty sure there is a person who will guide me through it :)